# Как удалить данные до конца строки после запятой?

Tags: linux, windows, powershell, active-directory

Есть текстовый файл:

> "CN=Username Alibabaev,OU=?????? ????????????,OU=???ep. ????????,OU=??? \"???????? ??????\",DC=domain,DC=ru"
>
> "CN=SUsername DAlibabaev,OU=?????? ????????????,OU=???ep.
>   ????????,OU=??? \"???????? ??????\",DC=domain,DC=ru"
>
> "CN=Supeman Batman,OU=??,OU=22 ????????,DC=domain,DC=ru"
>
> "CN=Sergio Amanol,OU=??,OU=22 ????????,DC=domain,DC=ru"
>
> "CN=username,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=ru"

Нужно удалить то что идёт после `"CN=User Suser`,  на всех строках. Как можно это сделать?

Comment: так linux или powershell? Ответ может быть совсем разным.

Comment: Поподробнее, пожалуйста. Ибо указанной подстоки `"CN=User Suser` я в приведенном примере файла не наблюдаю.

Comment: А чо делать с последней строкой? Оставить повторное `CN=...` или удалить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На PowerShell тоже элементарно:

```
cat filename.txt | %{$_.split(',')[0]}
```

Если нужно получить только имена пользователей без `CN=`, то так:

```
cat filename.txt | %{$_.split('=,')[1]}
```

`cat` - это алиас для `Get-Content`, `%` - алиас для `Foreach-Object` (для обработки каждой строки).

Answer (score 5):

В linux задача решается с помощью awk элеметарно (при условии, что в CN нет символа запятой)

```
cat filename.txt | awk -F, '{ print $1; }'
```

`-F,` - опция `awk` задающая разделитель (в данном случае `,`, по умолчанию - пробел или группа пробельных символов), потом выводим первое поле. Проблемы возникнут при создании пользователя с именем `Василий, Алибабаевич`

Поскольку powershell совсем не знаю, на виндах бы решил средствами python или perl, благо устанавливаются совсем просто.

В целом, проблема запятой в имени тоже решается несложно, если нужно напишу скрипт на perl, там буквально пара-тройка строк будет.

Comment: На винде можно поставить cygwin и решить тем же способом )

Comment: Вы просто волшебники) Спасибо всем